# How do I print text on the blue screen?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have one of problem. How do I print text on the blue screen?

```
start:
        mov ax, 07C0h
        add ax, 288
        mov ss, ax
        mov sp, 4096
        mov ax, 07C0h
        mov ds, ax
;-------------------------------------------------
        mov ah, 09h
        mov cx, 1000h
        mov al, 20h
        mov bl, 17h
        mov si, text_string
        int 10h
        jmp $
        text_string db 'This is my Operating System!', 0
print_string:
        mov ah, 0Eh
.repeat:
        lodsb
        cmp al, 0
        je .done
        int 10h
        jmp .repeat
.done:
        ret
        times 510-($-$$) db 0
        dw 0xAA55
```

This is my code. I write `mov si, text_string` but it not works. Please help me.

Comment: `47` is is `2F` and that's green not blue and you don't even call your `print_string`. Also that will not print the text **on** the blue screen.

Comment: Are you wanting to clear the entire screen blue or are you trying to print characters individually with a blue background?

Comment: @MichaelPetch The attribute 17h would produce WhiteOnBlue,the opposite of what you just wrote!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I edited.

Comment: @SepRoland I meant white on blue which is what the OP appears to have wanted. The value 17h still applies.

Comment: diswithend : You do realize that `17` and `17h` are not the same thing? The value 17 is in decimal. 17 decimal = 11h. 11h is blue on blue. You want `17h` since that is white on blue.

Comment: Hello everyone, I wrote `mov bl, 17h`. Thanks so much. it works! Thanks, thanks!!

Comment: accepting an answer already marks your question as answered.  Don't put stuff like "closed" or "solved" in the title.

Comment: Ok, Peter Cordes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *print_string* routine uses the BIOS teletype function to put characters on screen. Unfortunately this function will not output in any particular color when dealing with the text mode screens.

Since your aim is to print characters on the blue screen, first make sure the screen is actually blue.

```
        mov dx, 184Fh   ; lower right (79,24)
        xor cx, cx      ; upper left (0,0)
        mov bh, 1Fh     ; brightwhite on blue
        mov ax, 0600h   ; clear screen
        int 10h
```

Hereafter you can `call` your *print_string* routine that uses the BIOS teletype function:

```
        mov  si, text_string
        call print_string
        jmp  $

        text_string db 'This is my Operating System!', 0

print_string:
        mov  ah, 0Eh
        jmp  .first
.print: int  10h
.first: lodsb
        test al, al
        jnz  .print
        ret
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that unlike a normal clear screen this doesn't set the cursor to the upper left of the screen (you'd have to call int 10/ah=2 after for that behavior).

Comment: On a side note, this also assumes that the current text mode screen size is 80x25. You could read the size from the BDA doing something like: `push ds`
        `xor cx, cx`
        `mov ds, cx`
        `mov dh, [484h]`
        `mov dl, [44ah]`
        `dec dl`
        `mov bh, 1Fh`
        `mov ax, 0600h`
        `int 10h`
        `pop ds`